# Ошибка проверки сертификата SSLError python telebot при подключении через proxy

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, proxy

Работаю через корпоративную сеть, есть потребность написать телеграмм бота, пробовал различные библиотеки (`telebot, telepot, telegram, airogram`). Везде сталкиваюсь с проблемой доступа через корпоративный прокси. Сейчас остановился на telebot, подсунул прокси, теперь ошибка с проверкой сертификата.
Пробовал использовать http, https, socks5, socks5h, socks4 успеха не принесло.

```
import telebot
import json
from telebot import apihelper

with open('params.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
username = data['username']
password = data['password']
access_token_tg = data['access_token_tg']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(access_token_tg)
apihelper.proxy = {'https': f'https://{username}:{password}@10.0.18.139:3131'}
print(bot.get_me())
```

Получаю в ответ ошибку.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /мой токен тут/getMe (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Попробовал общаться через request с телегой, удалось подключиться, только после отключения проверки ssl `session.verify = False`. Но через запросы очень проблематично писать, собственно и библиотек для этого куча есть.

````
import pprint
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
import urllib3
import requests
import json

# читаем конфиг
with open('params.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
username = data['username']
password = data['password']
access_token_tg = data['access_token_tg']

# создаем сессию для работы с ботом
auth = HTTPProxyAuth(username, password)
proxies = {'https': f'https://{username}:{password}@10.0.18.139:3131'}
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = proxies
session.auth = auth

# отрубили проверку сертификата и варнинга
urllib3.disable_warnings()
session.verify = False

MAIN_URL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{access_token_tg}'
res = session.post(f'{MAIN_URL}/getMe').json()
pprint.pprint(res)```
Таким образом работает.

Прошу помочь разобраться или может мануал или библу другую посоветовать, 2 неделю бьюсь с этим.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте напрямую модифицировать библиотеку для работы с API телеграмма.

Если вы устанавливали библиотеку напрямую в python, то она находится в следующей директории:

```
Python{версия}/Lib/site-packages/{имя_библиотеки}
```

Если в виртуальном окружении работаете, то она находится в:

```
{имя_виртуального_окружения}/Lib/site-packages/{имя_библиотеки}
```

Находите модуль отвечающий за запросы, в большинстве библиотек для взаимодействия с API его проектируют так, что запросы выполняются в одной функции, её и надо модифицировать. На примере я показываю pyTelegramBotAPI, функция *_make_request* лежит в **../Lib/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py** и выглядит так (код частично срезан чтобы выделить главные детали):

```
def _make_request(token, method_name, method='get', params=None, files=None):
    if API_URL:
        request_url = API_URL.format(token, method_name)
    else:
        request_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/{1}".format(token, method_name)

    read_timeout = READ_TIMEOUT
    connect_timeout = CONNECT_TIMEOUT
    #...
    if RETRY_ON_ERROR:
        got_result = False
        current_try = 0
        
        while not got_result and current_try<MAX_RETRIES-1:
            current_try+=1
            
            try:
                result = _get_req_session().request(
                    method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
                    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
                got_result = True
                
            except HTTPError:
                #...
        if not got_result:
            result = _get_req_session().request(
                    method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
                    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
    else:
        result = _get_req_session().request(
            method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
            timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
    #...
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
    if json_result:
        return json_result['result']
```

В pyTelegramBotAPI _get_req_session() возвращает объект requests.Session(), а значит чтобы убрать сертификат или добавить свой, здесь хватит модифицировать строки с отправкой запроса (в примере кода отключается проверка сертификата):

```
result = _get_req_session().request(
            method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
            timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy, verify=False)
```

Если библиотека асинхронная, там используется aiohttp, как там работать с сертификатами описано в [документации](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#ssl-control-for-tcp-sockets). Я привёл пример только с одной синхронной библиотекой, но во всех +- принцип решения данной проблемы такой же.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, поправил, полет отличный!